# Athari, Ash'ari & Maturidi - Which one?

Tags: hadith, allah, prophet-muhammad, aqidah

As-salaamu alaykum!

I converted to Islam last year and I'm really confused which theological thought or school is the correct one? The Atharis will accuse the Ash'aira that they reject the attributes of Allah meanwhile the Ash'ari accuse Atharis of likening Allah to his creation.

This is really confusing.

Comment: As is written this question attracts subjective answers, which leads to the fact that this question could be understood as not answerable within the scope of this site. Nevertheless, I'd strongly suggest you to leave this choice and all these kinds of discussion and start to understand Islam first and to understand Allah as HE describes Himself "There is nothing like unto Him, and He is the Hearing, the Seeing." ([42:11](https://legacy.quran.com/42/11)).

Answer (score 2):

Wa 'Alaykoum Salam wa RahmatulLa !

Know that as long as you study the 'aqida according to any of these 3 schools from a traditional point of view (and not influenced by the Wahhabiyya movement), you are Sunni Insh'Allah and don't worry too much about it, go to whoever is most accessible for you to learn the basics of Muslim beliefs, for the details and what is divergent you will see once you have learned the basics.

Wa Allahua'lem